# Unable to read content from PDF file using Aspose PDF in Java

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.pdf

I'm trying to search for a string in a PDF file using AsposePdf.

This is what I'm doing:

```
String path = "C:/Windows/Fonts";
List list = Document.getLocalFontPaths();
list.add(path);
Document.setLocalFontPaths(list);
Document pdfDocument = new Document("myFile.pdf");
PageCollection pages = pdfDocument.getPages();
TextAbsorber textAbsorber = new TextAbsorber
  (new TextExtractionOptions(TextExtractionOptions.TextFormattingMode.Raw));  

for(int i = 1; i <= pages.size(); i++){
    Page currentPage = pdfDocument.getPages().get_Item(i);
    currentPage.accept(textAbsorber);
    String abText = textAbsorber.getText();
    String[] abArray = abText.trim().split("\n");
    for (String txtArray : abArray) {
         if (txtArray.contains("SomeText")) {
                //do something
              }
        }
 }
```

NullPointerException at: `currentPage.accept(textAbsorber);`

Error stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z11.m2(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z11.m7(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z13.m1(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z13.m1(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z13.m6(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z13.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z13.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.pdf.TextAbsorber.visit(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.pdf.Page.accept(Unknown Source)
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to split or trim the strings from the PDF file in order to extract any text. Aspose.PDF API supports extraction of text efficiently. Please try using below code snippet to extract text from a PDF document.

```
// Open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document("input.pdf");

// Create TextAbsorber object to find all instances of the input search phrase
TextFragmentAbsorber textFragmentAbsorber = new TextFragmentAbsorber("SEARCH STRING");

// Accept the absorber for first page of document
pdfDocument.getPages().accept(textFragmentAbsorber);

// Get the extracted text fragments into collection
TextFragmentCollection textFragmentCollection = textFragmentAbsorber.getTextFragments();

// Loop through the Text fragments
for (TextFragment textFragment : (Iterable<TextFragment>) textFragmentCollection) {
    // Iterate through text segments
    for (TextSegment textSegment : (Iterable<TextSegment>) textFragment.getSegments()) {
        System.out.println("Text :- " + textSegment.getText());
    }
}
```

For further information about text extraction, you may visit [Search and Get Text from Pages of a PDF Document](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfjava/Search+and+Get+Text+from+Pages+of+a+PDF+Document). In case you face any problem, please share the source PDF file with us while mentioning the text you want to extract.

**PS:** *I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.*

Comment: Same error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z11.m2(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z11.m7(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z13.m1(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z13.m1(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z13.m6(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z13.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.internal.p51.z13.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.TextFragmentAbsorber.visit(Unknown Source)
 at com.aspose.pdf.Page.accept(Unknown Source)

Comment: This process and the process I mentioned works for most of the files but for few files, there is an issue with Absorber. Is it something to do with encoding/font issues?

Comment: It appears like a file specific problem. Please share the source file which reproduces this exception, by uploading it to Google Drive, Dropbox etc. We will then investigate and share our findings with you. Moreover, before sharing requested data, please ensure using Aspose.PDF for Java 18.4 in your environment.